# How to apply force towards direction using mouse drag and/or touch input direction and input speed?

Tags: unity

I've to object. I can move object 1 (my Player) using mouse (or Touch for smartphone version).

I want apply a force to object 2 when object 1 hit it. Force direction must be mouse vector direction or touch vector direction.

For Mouse input i'm using event OnMouseDown and OnMouseDrag to determine mouse original position.

But I think this is not the best approach. Behaviour is not what i am expecting

```
void OnMouseDown()
    {

        mouseDragStartPosition = Input.mousePosition;

        //translate the cubes position from the world to Screen Point
        screenSpace = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

        //calculate any difference between the cubes world position and the mouses Screen position converted to a world point  
        offset = transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenSpace.z));

    }


    void OnMouseDrag()
    {


        //keep track of the mouse position
        var curScreenSpace = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenSpace.z);

        //convert the screen mouse position to world point and adjust with offset
        var curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenSpace) + offset;


        transform.position = new Vector3(curPosition.x, ClampY, curPosition.z);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter");
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Disc")
        {
            ApplyForce();
        }

    }



 void ApplyForce()
    {
        Vector3 direction = mouseDragStartPosition - Input.mousePosition;
        direction = new Vector3(direction.x, ClampY, direction.z); //ClampY used to not allow +-Y
        DiscRb.AddForce(direction * 1, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your direction vector is pointed in the wrong direction, it should be `Input.mousePosition - mouseDragStartPosition`. Also is your game 2D, as unitys 2D mode uses x and y as horizontal and vertical and z as depth. If this is the case you want to be using your x and y components of your direction vector and setting the z to 0. `direction.z = 0`.

Comment: And can you describe what the resulting behavior of your code is, all you say is that it is not what you are expecting.